# How to use Objective-C enum in Swift

Tags: swift

I have 2 enum definition in Objective-C file and Swift file.

**Japanese.h**

```
typedef enum {
  JapaneseFoodType_Sushi = 1,
  JapaneseFoodType_Tempura = 2,
} JapaneseFoodType;
```

**US.swift**

```
enum USFoodType {
  case HUMBERGER;
  case STEAK;
}
```

as we know, I can use Objective-C enum like following;

**Japanese.m**

```
- (void)method {
  JapaneseFoodType type1 = JapaneseFoodType_Sushi;
  JapaneseFoodType type2 = JapaneseFoodType_Tempura;
  if (type1 == type2) {// this is no problem
  }
}
```

But I can not use Objective-C enum in Swift file like following;

```
  func method() {
    var type1: USFoodType = USFoodType.HUMBERGER// no problem
    var type2: USFoodType = USFoodType.HUMBERGER// no problem
    if type1 == type2 {

    }

    var type3: JapaneseFoodType = JapaneseFoodType_Sushi// no problem
    var type4: JapaneseFoodType = JapaneseFoodType_Tempura// no problem
    if type3 == type4 {// 'JapaneseFoodType' is not convertible to 'Selector'

    }
  }
```

Is this a bug of Swift? And how can I use Objective-C (C) enum in Swift file?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I think this is a bug because Swift should define `==` for C enums or an "to Int" conversion but it doesn't.

The simplest workaround is redefining your C enum as:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, JapaneseFoodType) {
    JapaneseFoodType_Sushi = 1,
    JapaneseFoodType_Tempura = 2,
};
```

which will allow LLVM to process the enum and convert it to a Swift enum (`NS_ENUM` also improves your Obj-C code!).

Another option is to define the equality using reinterpret hack:

```
public func ==(lhs: JapaneseFoodType, rhs: JapaneseFoodType) -> Bool {
    var leftValue: UInt32 = reinterpretCast(lhs)
    var rightValue: UInt32 = reinterpretCast(rhs)

    return (leftValue == rightValue)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!
I'll use NS_ENUM to solve this problem (or wait to the apple's bugfix)
I didn't know that we can override operator like C++.

Comment: thank you my  problem solved.

Comment: my `Objective C` `enum` is defined with `NS_ENUM`, but still having problem with the call of enum.

Comment: @Sulthan what is `reinterpretCast`?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Something that doesn't exist in Swift any more, I guess. This was an answer for Swift 1.x. Nowadays, you would probably use `withMemoryRebound`.

Answer (score 25):

You should use `NS_ENUM` macro to make your enums Swift-compatible.

Also note that your enum literals should be accessed like `JapaneseFoodType._Sushi`, so it's probably a good idea to remove the underscore.