# Bridging objective-c NSUInteger NS_ENUM in Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I am attempting to bridge an objective-c SDK to a swift implementation. I have an example of what the implementation would be in objective-c but don't seem to be able to implement this in a workable solution in swift. Enum in objective-c header file below:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MTSCRATransactionStatus)
{
    TRANS_STATUS_OK,
    TRANS_STATUS_START,
    TRANS_STATUS_ERROR
};
```

Objective-C usage:

```
- (void)onDataEvent:(id)status
{
     //[self clearLabels];
     switch ([status intValue]) {
           case TRANS_STATUS_OK:
                NSLog(@"TRANS_STATUS_OK");
                break;
           case TRANS_STATUS_ERROR:
                NSLog(@"TRANS_STATUS_ERROR");
                break;
           default:
           break;
     } 
 }
```

I would need to change this into a swift equivalent. However I cannot get this work and have tried different casting of the status.

```
func trackDataReady (notification: NSNotification) {

    let status = notification.userInfo?["status"] as? NSNumber

    self.performSelector(onMainThread: 
     #selector(CardReaderClass.onDataEvent), with: status, 
     waitUntilDone: true)

}


func onDataEvent (status: Any) {

    switch status.intValue {

        case .TRANS_STATUS_START:
            print("TRANS_STATUS_START")
            break
        case .TRANS_STATUS_OK:
            print("TRANS_STATUS_OK")
            returnData()
            break
        case .TRANS_STATUS_ERROR:
            print("TRANS_STATUS_ERROR")
            returnError()
            break
    }

}
```

While this may appear to be a duplicate of [How to use Objective-C enum in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078245/how-to-use-objective-c-enum-in-swift)

The main issues is around this line of code:

```
[status intValue]
```

What would the Swift equivalent be given the NS_ENUM.

**EDIT**
**SOLUTION**

```
func onDataEvent (status: Any) {

    if let statusInt = status as? Int {
        if let newStatus = MTSCRATransactionStatus(rawValue: UInt(statusInt)) {

            switch newStatus {
            case .TRANS_STATUS_START:
                print("TRANS_STATUS_START")
                break
            case .TRANS_STATUS_OK:
                print("TRANS_STATUS_OK")
                returnData()
                break
            case .TRANS_STATUS_ERROR:
                print("TRANS_STATUS_ERROR")
                returnError()
                break
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Objective-C enum in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078245/how-to-use-objective-c-enum-in-swift)

Comment: @the4kman I have added a few new lines to the problem to explain where I am having this issue.

Comment: `status.intValue` is an `Int`, but you don't need an `Int`, you need an `MTSCRATransactionStatus`. `MTSCRATransactionStatus` is an enum whose `rawValue` is `Int`. That's a hint.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka thank you! That was the exact hint I needed.